# When creating forms, are fieldsets a viable option anymore?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, styling

I'm creating a few web forms that have areas to them.

Are fieldsets viable options for sectioning forms anymore?

Should I just use a div with styles to be similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fieldsets make more sense semantically. However, different browsers render them slightly differently, but you can achieve some pretty good [cross browser results](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/fieldset/). I guess it boils down to how pixel-perfect you need your design to be.

Answer (score 3):

The fieldset tag is still an acceptable control to use, I use it on occasion myself.  However, personally I find that since it renders slighly differnt in the browsers that I prefer to use a styled div, so I can be assured of the display format.

Answer (score 2):

Fieldsets are definitely better when it comes to structuring forms in an accessible way - Screenreaders and the likes will have the option of skimming through your form quickly. On a very short form - for example a Search or similar it isn't really needed thou.